# PHP swap 0 with +44

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, phone-number

I get the following variable

```
$inputMobile = $_POST["inputMobile"];
```

Now numbers can come in a variety of ways e.g.

```
07714....
+447714...
00447714...
```

What I need to do is make sure that whatever number I get, I change it to start with +44.  I had something like this

```
$inputMobile = $_POST["inputMobile"];
    if (substr($inputMobile, 0, 1) === '+44') { 
        $inputMobile = $_POST["inputMobile"];
    }
    else {
        $inputMobile = preg_replace('/^0?/', '+44', $inputMobile);
    }
```

The problem is, if I give it a number like +447714, it returns +44+44714.

How can I stop this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: "If the first character is this sequence of three characters..." might be the crux of your problem here.

Comment: `substr($inputMobile, 0, 1) === '+44'` can never be `true`.

Answer (score 8):

As others have pointed out, you are using `substr` incorrectly by comparing a 3-character string (`+44`) to a 1-character string (`substr($inputMobile, 0, 1)`). Try this, instead:

```
$inputMobile = $_POST["inputMobile"];

$inputMobile = preg_replace('/^(0*44|(?!\+0*44)0*)/', '+44', $inputMobile);
```

What this is does is replace a leading `044` or `44` (as well as any following zeroes) with `+44` and, if the number doesn't have a leading `044` or `44`, just adds `+44` at the beginning.

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/qF1fC9/1). The following examples:

```
07714....
+447714...
00447714...
```

are all standardized and become `+447714`.